# Put the result of the SELECT query into WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

The idea was to add window where user can find any student in database. However I've got an error ***that the column name is wrong.***
My method' code

```
string connStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                        AttachDBFileName=C:\Users\Чак\Desktop\ботанизм\ООП\coursework.start\CourseWorkFinal\CourseWorkFinal\University11.mdf;
                        Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();
        //idstudent={0} AND Name={1} AND Surname={2} AND Middlename={3} AND House={4} AND Street={5} AND Telephone={6}
        string BETA = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Name={0}", "Bob");//textbox1.Text 
        SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(BETA, conn);
        DataTable x = new DataTable();
        a.Fill(x);//<-there is an exception
        this.dataGrid1.DataContext = x;
        conn.Close();
```

XAML code

```
         <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="227" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="198,12,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="443" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

I've got such name in database. Why I've got such exception?

Comment: What happens when you execute the query in a non-WPF application?

Comment: Try to specify the schema of table (dbo) and use single quotes around the curly brackets.

Comment: And then there will be sql injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line of code:

```
string BETA = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Name={0}", "Bob");//textbox1.Text
```

This needs to be changed to:

```
string BETA = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Name='{0}'", "Bob");//textbox1.Text
```